# How can I use the lstsample environment (lstdoc package) in article?

Tags: listings, examples

I would like to try the `lstsample` environment from the `lstdoc` package, distributed with the [`listings` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings).

For that I have written the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lstdoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstsample}{}{}
  \color{blue}
  \lipsum[68]
\end{lstsample}

\end{document}
```

But it fails compilation with the message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\lst@sampleInput ->\MakePercentComment 
                                       \catcode `\^^M=10\relax \small \lst@s...
l.10     \end{lstsample}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but why not use the [`showexpl`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showexpl) package instead?

Comment: @Jubobs I have tried `showexpl` but it seems not to be able to break the output of the commands in its `LTXexample` environment across pages. Therefore I am looking for alternatives, as I need this feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `lstdoc` package is primarily meant to be used in documents using the `ltxdoc` class. That class loads the `doc` class internally, which contains two macro definitions that are particularly relevant here:

```
\def\MakePercentIgnore{\catcode`\%9\relax}
\def\MakePercentComment{\catcode`\%14\relax}
```

Because the `lstsample` environment needs those two macros, but the class you're using, `article`, doesn't define them, LaTeX rightfully reports those macros as undefined when you attempt to compile your code. Adding the two definitions shown above in your preamble will solve that problem.

Also, one quirk of the `lstsample` environment is that, for everything to work properly, **all the lines within it must start by a `%` followed by at least 4 spaces**. Follow that rule and you shall be happy.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lstdoc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% The following definitions are taken from doc.dtx.
% see http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/doc.dtx
\def\MakePercentIgnore{\catcode`\%9\relax}
\def\MakePercentComment{\catcode`\%14\relax}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstsample}{}{}
%    \color{blue}
%    \lipsum[68]  
\end{lstsample}

\end{document}
```